# Contacts management

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have Marketing cloud Connect syncing Objects and Contacts from Salesforce.
We find that there are unwanted Contacts coming through as part of the sync e.g. InACTIVE accounts.

What is the best way to delete them automatically? Is there filters that can be applied before the object is synced to Marketing Cloud?

My thinking: Creating a query which brings these contacts into a DE --> then they are manually deleted periodically. Can this step be automated?

Keen to hear if there are any other suggestions around this & ways to automate this process.

Comment: Did you put any filter criteria on what records to sync, when configuring Synchronised Data Sources?

Comment: Seeing the records coming in it doesn't look we did. I will need to confirm with the agency who set this up for us.

Comment: Before you delete any you will want to ensure you stop syncing them

Comment: Thank you. I will discuss with the implementation agency. Some of them are duplicates which I will compare and delete at CRM.

Comment: I just found there is a field in the Contact object which if True syncs the Contact. This field has a formula which determines whether its value is True or False. We will manipulate the formula to only bring relevant Contacts into MC. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.